# heroku django failed to detect set buildpack

Tags: python, django, heroku, buildpack

I was trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku.

but this is the error I face:

```
Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
```

I have tried everything I could. no help

what could be wrong?

this is the project structure:

```
project name:  api_test
```

and directories:

```
api_main  api_test  check.py  db.sqlite3  manage.py  Procfile  requirements.txt  runtime.txt  venv
```

this is requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
bs4==0.0.1
Django==1.10.5
djangorestframework==3.5.4
gunicorn==19.6.0
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0
```

and this is runtime.txt:

```
python-3.6.0
```

I tried to add buildpack, but it fails

Comment: Did you tried manually adding buildpack in settings ?

Comment: yeah..did that too...didn't work

Answer (score 1):

i was not able to initialize git properly. It was actually initialized in parent directory and that caused the error.

so if you're facing such error then have a check on your git initialization.